# Convey status updates without enum or reflection

Tags: c#, enums, status, typechecking

So I have this status enum which I use in to convey status updates in some classes:

```
public enum Status
{
    Pending,
    Waiting,
    Started,
    Finished,
    Cancelled,
    Failed,
    Incomplete
}
```

Now I realize this is less then ideal, I´d have to constantly add to the enum if I want to convey a new status, plus I can´t add any functionality (like a message for the user) easily.

So my first thought was to make an abstract base status class and derive from there. But then I´d have to do type checking at some point, to make certain actions happen for certain status updates.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes there is - you can use e.g. the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to solve your issue.

Comment: why not just store this status in a database?

Comment: @MarkusSafar that seems perfect, thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome ;-)